# regex add symbol in first and second line

Tags: regex, notepad++

please help..

I have 300k data, that need manage use regex add some symbol. what symbol I need to add is |

First Line Text **|**
Second Line Text **|**

the problem now. my data first line and second line is random, no any patern for regex rule. is that possible to do? thanks

Comment: You'd better use a scriptable editor, but the following regex should work fine in notepad++ assuming your pointer is somewhere on the first line : match `([^\r\n]*)(\R)([^\r\n]*)`, replace by `\1|\2\3|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\A.+\K(\R.*$)`
- Replace with: `|$1|`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\A          # beginning of file
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
(           # group 1
    \R      # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
    .*      # 0 or more any character but newline
    $       # end of line
)           # end group 1
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]